# Replace string containing variable name with sed in makefile

Tags: sed, makefile

I want to replace a string in Makefile by another one using sed:

```
* old string: $(ISM_DEPTH)/obj/lib/mylib.a
* new string: $(ENVIRONMENT_ROOT)/lib/
```

So, I used this command:

```
sed -e 's,$(ISM_DEPTH)/obj/lib/mylib.a,$(ENVIRONMENT_ROOT)/lib/,g' -i Makefile
```

The problem is that sed will replace $(ISM_DEPTH) and $(ENVIRONMENT_ROOT) by their values and I don't wont to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` character. To do so in Makefile it's needed to write double dollar - `$$`.:

```
sed -e 's,$$(ISM_DEPTH)/obj/lib/mylib.a,$$(ENVIRONMENT_ROOT)/lib/,g' -i Makefile
```